# Send key function not working properly in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy, sendkeys

Take a look at this site : https://www.arabam.com/ilan/sahibinden-satilik-mercedes-benz-cla-180-d-style/sahibinden-boyasiz-hasarsiz-cam-tavan-temiz-arac/14229201

I press end key so that it goes to the end of page. And then one by one it presses up key until it finds this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvSqo.png)

It was working just fine but it doesnt seem to  be working anymore.

```
  options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
        prefs = {}

        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2, "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,
                             executable_path='./chromedriver')
        d.get(features["ad_url"])
        # Use send_keys(Keys.HOME) to scroll up to the top of page
        d.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(
            Keys.END)
        while True:

                d.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(
                    Keys.UP)
                time.sleep(1)
                e = d.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div")
                if e.text:
                    break
```

Here is a fully functional code to try:

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pickle
import time


class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_1.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_2.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_3.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_4.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_5.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_6.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_7.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_8.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_9.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_10.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_11.xml','https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_12.xml',
                    'https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_13.xml']


    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/otomobil/', 'parse'),

    ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_FORMAT':'csv','FEED_URI': "arabam_"+str(datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%y'))+'.csv'
                       }

    def parse(self,response):


        for td in response.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/a"):
            link = td.xpath("@href").extract()


            year = td.xpath("text()").extract()
            self.crawled.append(link[0])
            self.new_links += 1
            if int(year[0]) > 2010:
                url = "https://www.arabam.com/" + link[0]

                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self,response):

        features = {}





        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        # options.add_argument('headless')
        options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
        prefs = {}

        prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2, "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
        options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
        d = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options,
                             executable_path='./chromedriver')
        d.get(features["ad_url"])
        # Use send_keys(Keys.HOME) to scroll up to the top of page
        d.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(
            Keys.END)
        while True:

                d.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(
                    Keys.UP)
                time.sleep(1)
                e = d.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div")
                if e.text:
                    break

        overview1 = e.text.split("\n")

        yield features



process = CrawlerProcess({
})


process.crawl(Myspider)
process.start() # the script wi
```

Edit:
I commented out and ran the code and it turns out that keys are being sent. The problem is with trying to find specific div. I tried putting try catch on it but that doesn't seem to be working.

while True:

```
        d.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(
            Keys.UP)
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            e = d.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div")
            if e.text:
                break
        except:
            pass
```

Edit:

This is what I did to scroll up. But unfortunately this doesn't work for most cases

```
for i in range(0,37):

        d.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(
            Keys.UP)
        time.sleep(1)

e = d.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div")

overview1 = e.text.split("\n")
```

Edit:
Tried this. It scrolls into view but doesnt get element

```
         e = d.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'js-hook-appendable-technicalPropertiesWrapper' and @class = 'cf' ] ")


        actions = ActionChains(d)
        actions.move_to_element(e).perform()
        wait = WebDriverWait(d, 20)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'js-hook-appendable-technicalPropertiesWrapper' and @class = 'cf' ]")))
        overview1 = e.text.split("\n")
```

Edit:
Screenshot of HTML
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxgco.png)

Comment: If you are having issues with an XPATH better to share an HTML code snippet of the element you are trying to capture as well. So others can see what is the issue.

Comment: I simply used inspect element of chrome. HTML might be too long for htis

Comment: At least provide a screenshot of the HTML of the element you are trying to capture. How else do we know which element you need our help in capturing? :)

Comment: On the last try, what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @debugger89 overview1 is ['']. There is no error message. Its just empty

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer as this is a bit lengthy comment.

First, you need to wait for the element to appear. And then find the element and extract the values. From your code, the element find is done before the visibility check.
And another thing you can try is to scroll to the specific element before extracting values. This specific table seems to be loading values only if it is in the viewport.

```
actions = ActionChains(d)
actions.move_to_element(e).perform()
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'js-hook-appendable-technicalPropertiesWrapper' and @class = 'cf' ]")))

e = d.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id = 'js-hook-appendable-technicalPropertiesWrapper' and @class = 'cf' ] ")
# Scroll to the element
d.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
# Check what is the actual text value you get
print(e.text)
print (e.text.split("\n"))
```